# Wooden surface sticky

Tags: wood

I build a wooden table and put stain on it. After some months I put lacquer on it, which is made for that kind of stain. After two, three weeks I realized that it doesn't really protect anything. When I slightly draw my nails across the surface you could clearly see scratches.
Therefore I used another lacquer I had left. This was for all kind: Cars, metal and also wood. Now it works, no scratches anymore but instead the surface is sticky. Not much but enough to recognize it after touching the table two, three times.

Has anyone an advice how to get rid of that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you have details of the sticky lacquer?  I've had some success with using a solvent that *doesn't* remove the coating, such as meths (denatured alchohol) to remove residual solvents.

Comment: _I build a wooden table and put stain on it_ Are you sure it was _just_ a stain? Not some sort of stain and finish product. Either way... What was the stain product exactly? If you want it done right you likely need to refinish the table now but would need to know more about the products used to be sure.

Comment: This question is definitely on topic here, but if you haven't checked it already, we also have a dedicated woodworking site (woodworking.stackexchange.com) that you might find has some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

There can be so many factors, that are not described here, that can lead to your problem. Simple things like, where do you live, is it moist most of the time? There are so many things that could affect lacquer drying. Lacquer takes a long time to dry, how does it smell right now? If it still smells the solvent of the lacquer, then it's not dry. Try putting it on a closed small room with a decent powered dehumidifier, for a couple of days, and see what happens. And until then, don't touch it (finger prints, scratches), no smell it's the best indication that it's dry. Good luck.